# Are /dev/i2c-1 and /dev/mem colliding?

Tags: block-device, c++, sensors, gpio, character-device

I write a program which should handle a motion sensor and an ultrasonic sensor at the same time. I'm using a Jetson Nano with 40 GPIO-pins. The first one uses I2C interface and thus accesses /dev/i2c-1 with the linux-intern libi2c-library while the other uses /dev/mem to write hex values directly to the pins.

Now when I run them separately, they work just fine, but when trying to combine them in one single code file, they crash. The I2C-sensor just gives an unknown error and freezes. I wanted to ask whether it is possible that they collide when used simultaneously and you have any suggestion how to avoid this? Is there a way to run an I2C-sensor and an ultrasonic sensor in parallel?

Thanks for the answers in advance!

Comment: Without knowing exactly how `/dev/mem` is used, the question "are the two access methods colliding?" is going to be impossible to answer. Is it just the program crashing/hanging, or does the kernel crash too? Is the problem caused by the different access methods, or just by an error in combining the two programs into one? Instead of `/dev/mem` you might want to use `/sys/class/gpio/*` or perhaps [libgpio](https://github.com/Linutronix/libgpio).

Comment: Your program you are writing... it runs in userspace ? Well... Being acknowledged that you do what you want with your system and agreeing with above comment, I'd say that considering all efforts linux kernels achieve since 2.6 to (wisely) restrict access to /dev/mem from userspace... I'd tend to consider a **very bad** practice for whatever userspace program to rely on such a driver. (To be honest... for having done this myself in the past... for quick&dirty reasons... I don't blame you. ;-) )

Comment: @telcoM Well, I tried to get into this libgpio thing and noticed there's not a documentation of the commands anywhere. I think I figured out how to output a HIGH signal, but the problem is it just not works, my ultrasonic sensor is not reacting in any way. Are you familiar with libgpio, what should I do now?